# Linux + IPTables + NAT = some http hosts unreachable

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I've set up dead simple NAT:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

Everything works almost ok. Almost.
The problem I've expirienced is some hosts are not reachable by NAT clients, i.e.
there's http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js - I can download it from server, but
in case of NAT client download stalls on connection stage. I thought its FFs fault, but wget has the same
issue. I didn't find any logs/messages that can shed some light on this situtation.
Any ideas what's going on?
Maybe some tricky thing in sysclt is causing this?

P.S. 3/3 client boxes are expiriencing this issue. This is definitely server trouble.

Comment: can you post iptables -L -v and iptables -L -v -t nat output?

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/288763/

Comment: What result of executing "telnet code.jquery.com 80 " on problem boxes? Also on linux run before attempt and stop after > tcpdump -vv -i etherwan host code.jquery.com

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: smart switch was dropping packets somewhy. Replaced it and now everything works.

Comment: which make/model was the device? I think i'm having a similar problem and this would confirm it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just before your iptables drops any packets, add a -j LOG, running the command again then check /var/log/messages and you'll probably find you're dropping some incoming related packets.

Comment: there are no DROP rules. none at all. the only rule iptables has is the one i added manually, all other chains and tables got policy=ACCEPT. dmesg and other logs are quiet on this.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like a NAT problem.

Check the output of `ifconfig -a` on the client machines. Do you see errors or dropped packets on the interface connected to your LAN?